# Spark and Tika for pdf parsing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-tika

I’m trying to parse a readable pdf located from hdfs .

I have imported the required jars

The problem I have is below after importing the pdf as a rdd

```
val data = sc.binaryFiles(“hdfs://xxxx/path/file.pdf)
```

The above creates a rdd, next I try to take the rdd to create a stream

```
val stream : InputStream = new FileInputStream(data)
```

> error: overload method constructor FileInputStream with alternatives :

Comment: Here is what I found somewhere: [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201503.mbox/%3CCAFmPnu5SzQ2oeXDEwC9ojAG4eCGdt6Y-6Frd8RbLb+vRScLSPA@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: Why do you want to convert HDFS file -> RDD -> InputStream? Any particular reason? Also it would be better to know what exactly you are trying to achieve. You should be able to read HDFS files using HDFS lib without using spark. Refer this example : https://gist.github.com/ashrithr/f7899fdfd36ee800f151#file-filesystemoperations-java-L82

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using spark and tika , here is my code

```
spark-shell --jars tika-app-1.8.jar

val binRDD = sc.binaryFiles("/hdfs_data_directory")

val textRDD = binRDD.map(file => {new org.apache.tika.Tika().parseToString(file._2.open( ))})

textRDD.saveAsTextFile("/output/")
```